# Eiffel: Where can I find a reference with common features lists?

Tags: eiffel

Am looking for typical

```
feature {NONE} -- Initialization (semantic)
feature -- Status Settings (semantic)
.....
```

Where can I find that list with semantic?

Didn't find it into [ECMA](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-367.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ECMA standard does not impose any specific style on the programs. An unfinished page describing [style guidelines](https://www.eiffel.org/doc/eiffel/Style_Guidelines#Feature_clause_header_comments) gives an example with the following feature clause comments:

- Initialization
- Access
- Status report
- Status setting
- Element change
- Removal
- Implementation

The dialog to [add a new feature](https://www.eiffel.org/doc/eiffelstudio/Feature_clauses#Feature_clause_names) in EiffelStudio lists some other common feature clause groups:

- Measurement
- Comparison
- Cursor movement
- Resizing
- Transformation
- Conversion
- Duplication
- Miscellaneous
- Basic operations
- Obsolete
- Inapplicable

EiffelStudio puts the same list of feature clauses when [adding a new class](https://www.eiffel.org/doc/eiffelstudio/New_class_command) to the system, provided that an option *"Generate default feature clauses"* is checked.

Standard kernel classes come with some more common categories, e.g.:

- Input
- Output
- Iteration

Comment: Into OOSC p.889 "Eighteen categories and the corresponding comments have been standardized for the
Base libraries, so that every feature (out of about 2000 in all) belongs to one of them. The
example above illustrates some of the most important categories." I remember having found the description of each one somewhere but unable to find it anymore... Thx for the answer